# stretching div across page does not work

Tags: javascript, css

I must be missing something very obvious but I'm simply trying:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:gray">
bla
</div>
```

But the `div` does not stretch across the page.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Ld4p68L/3/)

Why does this not work and how can I make it work ?

Comment: To be clear, you mean to have the div cover *The entire width of the page* and not the entire height?

Comment: You have 4 appropriate answers to your question, please mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/5o65ptcr/2/

Apply this CSS to HTML and Body:

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

The problem is that the HTML and BODY tags have default margin (behaves like padding) applied to them in the user-agent stylesheet (the stylesheet that is built in to the browser).

UPDATE: Considering the question, I thought you meant the *"entire width of the page"* and not the entire height. I have updated my question to include both the entire width and entire height. Please be sure you explain your question accurately.

Comment: still doesn't fill the page

Comment: @kofifus You said "Stretch across the page", I thought you meant the width of the page not the entire height. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:gray;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">
bla
</div>
```

Divs are relative to their parents. So if the body element doesn't have height 100% also then the div can't stretch across the screen. You would have to position it absolute then it would stretch across the page as it's not longer restricted by it's parent and moved to it's own layer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `height:100%;` to `html` and `body`.

```
body,
html
{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Ld4p68L/5/)

Comment: ah I see, but why no width:100% ?

Comment: @kofifus `width:100%; do the same thing. `div` have `display:block;` by default. It means it is stretched in one line so if you remove `width:100%` it can fits in 100% of its parent. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Ld4p68L/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting `vw` , `vh` `css` units for `%`

```html
<div style="width:100vw;height:100vh;background-color:gray;">
  bla
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4Ld4p68L/4/